# Is there a way to stroke a path with a solid color in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I manually outlined part of an image with the pen tool and now I'd like to draw a single solid color outline around it (white border). But it has to be all one exact color, no feathering anti aliasing, etc.  Just an outline of white (255,255,255) pixels. It's for a machine learning project.  Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set the *Foreground Color* to the color you want to stroke with.
- Select the *Pencil Tool* and select the *Brush Size* you want for the stroke.
- Select the path you want to stroke with *Path Selection Tool*.
- Right-click the path and select *Stroke Path*.
- Set *Tool* to *Pencil* and click *OK*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Draw a shape with the pen tool and set it's stroke options..

[image]

You can even do this with open paths in Photoshop...

[image]

Comment: Much simpler than my answer, but how do you disable *anti-aliasing*?

Comment: @Wolff because it's vector it'll stay crisp. But there will *always* be a minute amount of anti-aliasing.  If the desire is strictly the hard pixel stair step... then the pencil tool is better. I, perhaps incorrectly, assumed the question was more about soft edges than actual hard pixel stair steps.

Comment: I suspect, since the OP mentions "machine learning", that some script will analyze the pixels and that the stroke needs to be easily detectable. So not really "graphic design".